# How do I reload my JS files using browse-sync with GULP JS?

Tags: javascript, gulp

I created a project with gulp js, installed bootstrap, browse-sync and sass.

My `gulpfile.js` file looks like this:

```js
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
const sass = require('gulp-sass')(require('sass'));

gulp.task('sass', () => {
  return gulp.src("./sass/*.scss")
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest("dist/"))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});

gulp.task('start', gulp.series('sass', function() {
  browserSync.init({
    server: "./"
  });

  gulp.watch("sass/*.scss", gulp.series('sass'));
  gulp.watch("./*.html").on('change', browserSync.reload);
}));

gulp.task('default', gulp.series('start'));
```

When I use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> command in HTML and SCSS files, my project is saved and browser is reloaded; but I want to do this also for my JS files. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Very similar to the way you are dealing with your css, but you can use other plugins like [terser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-terser) to compress your javascript. Here is my js function which [concatenates](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concat) and minifies my javascript before reloading via browsersync

```
const concat = require('gulp-concat');
const terser = require('gulp-terser'); 

function js() { 
  return src(['./js/*.js'])
  .pipe(concat('scripts.min.js'))
  .pipe(terser())
  .pipe(dest('js'))
  .pipe(browsersync.stream());
}
```